# PostgreSQL support for PHP on MacOS X

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I am new using mac, and I have been trying to enable the pgsql module for php 5.5.36 in OS X El Capitan without results.

At first I tried using

`brew install php55 --with-postgresql`

and

`brew install php55-pdo-pgsql`

commands and add

`extension=pgsql.so` to /etc/php.ini

then `php -m`

the result list shows pdo_pgsql so I assumed that the module has been loaded succesfull, but when I open a php info file in the browser there isn't any pgsql information.

When I run `php -v` it shows :

> Warning: Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Also, I tried:

```
curl -O http://us.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.38.tar.gz
tar -xzvf php-5.5.38.tar.gz 
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

but nothing seems to result, can anyone guide me of what else can do?

Comment: I have had this happen to me, and why I ask. Is PostgreSQL working on your computer? Can you log into your local PostgreSQL in the command line with `psql`? I ask because if `which psql` in the command line doesn't return anything adding the extension in php wont know what psql libraries to load.

Comment: Using `which psql` return `/usr/local/bin/psql`